# Finding if customer has already products in last 2 months SQL Teradata to SQL SAS

Tags: sql, sas, teradata-sql-assistant

hope to find you well!

I have a table called "policies" that has the following data:

```
Date_begin_policy  Customer_id   Policy_id
01-09-2019             A            111
02-10-2019             A            123
09-07-2019             A            126
```

and i want to build 2 columns "has_policy_month_before" and "has_policy_month_less2" that for each date_begin_policy checks if customer has already other policies in date_begin_policy -1month and date_begin_policy - 2 month:

```
Date_begin_policy  Customer_id   Policy_id  has_policy_month_before   has_policy_month_less2
01-09-2019             A             111           no                         yes
02-10-2019             A             123           yes                        no
09-07-2019             A             126           no                         no
```

I would do it like this in Teradata sql:

```
select t1.customer_id
         , t1.policy_id
         , t1.date_begin_policy
         , case
             when trunc(t2.date_begin_policy, 'mm') >= add_months(trunc(t1.date_begin_policy, 'mm'), -1)
             then 'yes'
             else 'no'
           end as has_policy_month_before
         , case
             when trunc(t2.date_begin_policy, 'mm') <  add_months(trunc(t1.date_begin_policy, 'mm'), -1)
             then 'yes'
             else 'no'
           end as has_policy_month_less2
      from mvt_data as t1
 left join mvt_data as t2  on t2.customer_id                     = t1.customer_id
                          and trunc(t2.date_begin_policy, 'mm') >= add_months(trunc(t1.date_begin_policy, 'mm'), -2)
                          and trunc(t2.date_begin_policy, 'mm') <  trunc(t1.date_begin_policy, 'mm')
      where t1.customer_id = 'A'
   order by t1.policy_id asc;
```

but the problem is the add_months function and the trunc function are not like this in SAS. Could anyone please help me?

Please note i really would like to do it in sql and not sas syntax preferably.

Thanks

Comment: Just curious... your policies don't have expiration date?

Comment: yes they do... i'll have to think if for this specific case i need it but i dont think so

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to any teradata environment to test, but you can try with something like this:

```
select
  p.Date_begin_policy,
  p.Customer_id,
  p.Policy_id,
  case 
    when lag(p.Policy_id, 1) over (partition by p.Customer_id order by p.Date_begin_policy) is null 
     then 'no'
    else 'yes'
  end as has_policy_month_before,
  case 
    when lag(p.Policy_id, 2) over (partition by p.Customer_id order by p.Date_begin_policy) is null 
      then 'no'
    else 'yes'
  end as has_policy_month_less2
from policies p
```

Comment: `lag` function is likely familiar to you, because if I am not wrong it exists in SAS previous than in SQL

Comment: I want to use it in SAS not in Teradata :)